# I'm having an issue with not converting const__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long long int* , std:: vector<long long int>

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve a question from a Div 3 competition. I'm having troubles with line 25 and 26, it's saying

```
error: cannot convert ' const__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long long int*, std::vector<long long int>
```

I'm not too sure what's wrong. The goal for this line is to store the minimum of vector a and b into a long long integer amin and bmin.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

#define ll long long
#define ld long double
#define endl "\n"

void solve(){
    ll input;
    ll total;

    int amount; cin >> amount;
    vector<ll> a, b;
    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
        cin >> input;
        a.push_back(input);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
        cin >> input;
        b.push_back(input);
    }

    ll amin, bmin;
    amin = min(a.begin(), a.end());
    bmin = min(b.begin(), b.end());
    ll adif, bdif, totaldif;


    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
        adif = a[i] - amin;
        bdif = b[i] - bmin;
        totaldif = abs(adif - bdif);
        total += (adif - totaldif) + (bdif - totaldif) + totaldif;
    }

    cout << total << endl;



}


int main()
{

    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(0);

    int t; cin >> t;
    while(t--){
        solve();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::min` returns the minimum of 2 elements, not the minimum element of a range. Assuming you don't want the minimum of 2 iterators, but the minimum element of a range, you need `std::min_element` and you need to dereference the result, like this:

```
amin = * min_element(a.begin(), a.end());
    // ^
```

And you need to do the same thing for `bmin`.

---

Also, please avoid `using namespace std;` and all the `#define`s for the types, it just makes the code more confusing to read.

Comment: Oh okay, alright. Thanks. I see, std::min can only return 2 elements. Alright. Gotcha, thanks.

Comment: @FenixVictoria Well, it doesn't return 2 elements, it returns the minimum of 2 elements. You can also use `std::min` to return the minimum of multiple elements.

Comment: Well, I get that it's bad practice, but for competitive programming, it's to get out the answers and code the fastest way possible. It isn't meant for people to read them. I do get what you mean though, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @FenixVictoria If it isn't meant for people to read, then why are you posting it here, for people to read? That would explain the many down-votes your question received.